# What is the logic behind creating Autowired instance in case if container is having multiple instance

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I have a question regarding Autowiring.  Let me explain the scenario first.

I have 3 projects. `ProjectA`, `ProjectB` ,`ProjectC`. `ProjectA` is having dependency of `ProjectB` and `ProjectC` through pom.xml.
I have class `Test.java` in `ProjectA` which is having a property :

@Autowired
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

`ProjectB` and `ProjectC` each having following entry in their respective context xml file :

```
<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>
```

Now, My question is,`JdbcTemplate` instance of which project (ProjectB or ProjectC ? ) above mentioned Autowired proeprty will refer to?
In other words , Based on what logic it will create that instance ?

Answer (score 0):

I would simplify things little bit. Let me call `ProjectA` the `Application` and `ProjectB` and `ProjectC` the `libraries`.

Usually a library doesn't have to have `context.xml` or any other spring configuration inside, because it will not have a DI container of its own - the application (that uses it) will. So the application has a configuration of DI container and the application's configuration decides how to instantiate dependencies.

I believe this is true even if a library contains some spring configurations - those should be ignored.

Comment: In my application `ProjectB` and `ProjectC` are not libraries. These are projects like `ProjectA`. So those projects have their own context xml

Comment: But they act as libraries in ProjectA anyway and should not influence the configuration of its DI container. If it happens by coincedence, say, if ProjectA has no its own context.xml configuration and spring is picking up one from classpath (by default), then I'd say that ProjectA coonfiguration is wrong, because one cannot tell which context.xml will be uset (it will depend on order of libraries in classpath which may change at some point). Try to make pure libraries and make all the applications depend on libraries (not from other applications) or provide ProjectA with its own configuration.